# Rebuild the text of the outer class with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

The code below is a simplification of my project.
I want it make like: When you push the button, text is rebuilt and increase the number.
However, text isn't reloaded. but I detected that the number of `count` is actualy increased.

Why this text isn't reloaded? Some way to detect changes of other classes?

```
class CLS extends ChangeNotifier{
    int count = 0;
    void add(int i){
        count += i;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

....

class Main extends StatelessWidget{
    Widget txt(){
        return Consumer<CLS>(
          builder: (context, value, _) => Text(value.count.ToString())
        );
    }

    Widget but(int i){
        return ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Button"),
          onPressed: context.read<CLS>().add(i)
        );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Scaffold(
         body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => CLS(),
          child: Column( children: [
            txt(),
            but(1)
        ]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same context for providing and accessing your `Provider`, so it can't find it. You should use new `context` to access your provided `Provider`, because it looks for it's ancessor to find provided `Provider`. And also you should use that new `context` to read your `Provider` from your `but()` method, like so:

```
Widget but(int i, BuildContext ctx) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Button"), onPressed: () => ctx.read<CLS>().add(i));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => CLS(),
        child: Builder(builder: (ctx) { // new context(ctx) to find Provider from parent's(ancessor's) context
          return Column(
            children: [
              txt(),
              but(1, ctx), // use that new context in your but method for accessing Provider
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```